# C# displaying objects in List from a different class in Main

Tags: c#, list, class, inheritance

I am trying to print the items in the Lists to the console, and I am not sure if I am missing something blatantly obvious but I cannot figure out what to do to achieve this. My programming class from first semester basically taught me nothing and I have been learning bits and pieces on my own, so I am clueless as to how to do a lot of things. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class VendingMachine
{
    public List<Snack> snax = new List<Snack>();
    public List<Drink> drinx = new List<Drink>();

    public void displayInventory()
    {
        foreach (Snack s in snax)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");
            Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n");

        foreach (Drink d in drinx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());
        }
    }
}

public abstract class Items
{
    public string name;
    public int calories;

    public Items(string name, int calories)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.calories = calories;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (name + "    " + calories);
    }
}

public class Drink : Items
{
    int flOz;

    public Drink(string name, int calories, int flOz) : base(name, calories)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.calories = calories;
        this.flOz = flOz;
    }
}

public class Snack : Items
{
    int oz;

    public Snack(string name, int calories, int oz) : base(name, calories)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.calories = calories;
        this.oz = oz;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        VendingMachine Vend1 = new VendingMachine();

        Vend1.snax.Add(new Snack("Cookies", 125, 8));
        Vend1.snax.Add(new Snack("Chips", 100, 8));
        Vend1.snax.Add(new Snack("Nuts & Berries", 80, 8));

        Vend1.drinx.Add(new Drink("Soda", 180, 12));
        Vend1.drinx.Add(new Drink("Water", 0, 12));
        Vend1.drinx.Add(new Drink("Juice", 90, 12));

        var invoke = new VendingMachine();
        invoke.displayInventory();
    }
}
```

}

---

Update

I got the list to print, but I need to know how to print not only the item and calories, but also oz/flOz in the inherited classes. How might I do that? I looked at the assignment and it says to tweak the to string override but I am not sure what to put.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        VendingMachine Vend1 = new VendingMachine();

        Vend1.snax.Add(new Snack("Cookies", 125, 8));
        Vend1.snax.Add(new Snack("Chips", 100, 8));
        Vend1.snax.Add(new Snack("Nuts", 80, 8));

        Vend1.drinx.Add(new Drink("Soda", 180, 12));
        Vend1.drinx.Add(new Drink("Water", 0, 12));
        Vend1.drinx.Add(new Drink("Juice", 90, 12));

        Vend1.displayInventory();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried doing Console.Write(Vend1);  but it just prints the namespace

Comment: Vend1.displayInventory() should print the name and cals of all the snacks and drinks. doesn't it work?

printing the variable Vend1 will call Vend1.ToString() and print that. if ToString is not overriden then the default implimenation is the namespace and class.

Comment: @Rahul that's what i wrote.

Comment: @JustinL - Please don't edit your question to invalidate existing answers. I've fixed the editing so it should make more sense to everyone. Can you please check? Can you also use this style of updating in the future?

Comment: sorry, yes I will update in the future, I did not mean to confuse people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to output the `oz` and `flOz`, and to comply the with requirements, you need to override `.ToString()` in both `Drink` and `Snack`.

```
public class Drink : Items
{
    int flOz;

    public Drink(string name, int calories, int flOz) : base(name, calories)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.calories = calories;
        this.flOz = flOz;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + "    " + this.flOz;
    }
}

public class Snack : Items
{
    int oz;

    public Snack(string name, int calories, int oz) : base(name, calories)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.calories = calories;
        this.oz = oz;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + "    " + this.oz;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `Main()` function you're adding inventory to an object called `Vend1`, but then you are creating a second `VendingMachine` object called `invoke` and displaying it's inventory with `invoke.displayInventory()` (rather than displaying the inventory of `Vend1` with `Vend1.displayInventory()`).

If you want to see the inventory you added to `Vend1`, this snippet

```
VendingMachine invoke = new VendingMachine();
invoke.displayInventory();
```

should read

```
//VendingMachine invoke = new VendingMachine();
// ...or you could add items to the invoke object and display them instead
//invoke.displayInventory();

Vend1.displayInventory();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes, this was helpful, I am not sure why I did not think of this. I am completely new and overthink very simple things sometimes :)